# Jenkins Pipeline: How to archive artifacts when the build fails?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When our browser based tests fail, we take a screenshot of the browser window to better illustrate the problem. However, I don't understand how to archive them in my pipeline, because the pipeline stops after the failure. Same for the `junit.xml`, I'd also like to use it in error cases.

I've checked, the screenshots are generated and stored correctly.

My definition looks like this (irrelevant things mostly trimmed):

```
node {
   stage('Build docker container') {
       checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', ...])
       sh "docker build -t webapp ."
   }
   stage('test build') {
       sh "mkdir -p rspec screenshots"
       sh "docker run -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/webapp/rspec/junit.xml:/myapp/junit.xml -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/webapp/screenshots:/myapp/tmp/capybara -v webapp bundle exec rspec"
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit 'rspec/junit*.xml'
      archive 'screenshots/*'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple Java `try/catch` to avoid pipeline failure on test failure, or Jenkins [catchError](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-catcherror-code-catch-error-and-set-build-result) like this :

```
node {
    catchError {
        // Tests that might fail...
    }
    // Archive your tests artifacts
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/), you can use the post section in your pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            ...
        }
        stage('Test') {
            ...
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            archive 'build/libs/**/*.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `failure` not `always`